# Declaring variable w/o knowing the name

Tags: python, python-3.4

This may seem a weird question but the thing is that I have a class to which I want to assign a variable (so using `self.vname = Whatever` in `__init__`), but this variable name is passed as wkargs in the instantiation.

So the class looks like

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            self.what_do_i_type_here = kwargs[key]
```

Actually this is a class which I will extend then so I am not sure how to do this.

I want to create a generic class which in each extension case will have different variables defined.

How to do so, or how to carry out a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `setattr`:

```
for key, value in kwargs.items()
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

but I don't see the point, since you won't have any idea of the keys you've set so you won't be able to use them anywhere.

Why not keep them in a dictionary?

```
self.data = kwargs
```

then you can iterate through `self.data` and its values whenever you like.

Comment: Augh! It took a really long time to post my answer, and I see you posted almost exactly the same thing while it was loading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you want the variable name to be the key.

You can use the [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) built-in function:

```
for key in kwargs:
    setattr(self,key,kwargs[key])
```